# ESLint, TypeScript, Vue and WebPack Encore: Cannot disable ESLint rule

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, eslint, webpack-encore

I have spent some hours digging into Webpack Encore and ESLint issues, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

I specify that I want to change or turn off some TypeScript-ESLint rules, but nothing happens. I get linter warnings anyway. My configuration looks as follows:

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [
    "assets/scripts/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And here are the relevant parts of my encore configuration:

```js
Encore
  // ...
  .enableTypeScriptLoader()
  .enableForkedTypeScriptTypesChecking()
  .enableVueLoader()
  .enableEslintLoader((options) => {}, { lintVue: true })
  // ...
;
```

And this is the warning I receive, although I disabled the rule:

```
/some/path/my-file.ts
  97:82  warning  Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
```

To me, it seems like [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/pull/687) should fix my issue, but it does not.

Do you guys have any idea? I would be very grateful for any tip :)

**Edit:**

With [the help of lotype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63017240/1007003) and a coworker of mine, I finally found the solution. A couple of things must be changed.

First, make sure the correct parser is used:

```js
.enableEslintLoader((options) => {
  options.parser = require('./.eslintrc.json').parser;
  // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/eslint-loader/#cache
  options.cache = false; // optional, but recommended
}, { lintVue: true })
```

Then, make sure to add TypeScript rules to the override section, and "normal" rules to the rule section like this:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "warn"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for helping me with this, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you try putting it into the overrides section of your .eslintrc.json?

```
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Edit: "files" needed as per [specification](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-7.0.0#lint-files-matched-by-overrides-files-by-default)

Comment: Sadly, that was not it. However, thanks for the idea, it was worth a try!

Comment: Your answer was one part of the solution, so thank you very much! I will make this the accepted answer. Anyone with the same problem: Please see my question's edit!

Comment: Glad I could help!